# Scala: Returning an element from a list that matches a condition

Tags: list, scala, yield-keyword

I have a list and I am trying to write a function `returnMatchedElement(x:Int,y:Int,f:(Int,Int)=>Boolean)` such that if a certain condition matches on an element of the list, it will return that element. Here's what I have got so far:

```
def returnMatchedElement(x:Int,l:List[Int],f:(Int,Int)=>Boolean):Int={
 for (y<-l if f(x,y)) yield y 
0}
def matchElements(a:Int,b:Int):Boolean= {if a==b true else false} 
val l1=List(1,2,3,4,5)

returnMatchedElement(3,l1,matchElements)
res13: Int = 0
```

I am guessing I have a problem in understanding the `yield` keyword. What am I getting wrong here?

### EDIT

The answer below works (thanks for that), but only if f returns boolean. I tried another example like this

```
def matchElements(a:Int,b:Int):Int= {if (a==b) 1 else 0} 
def returnMatchedElement(x:Int,l:List[Int],f:(Int,Int)=>Int):Option[Int]={l.find(y => f(x, y))}
```

And now the compiler says

```
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Boolean
       def returnMatchedElement(x:Int,l:List[Int],f:(Int,Int)=>Int):Option[Int]={l.find(y => f(x, y))}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `{if a==b true else false} ` is the same as `a == b` ?

Comment: Yes, the actual function had another condition to match, I boiled it down. But thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The actual code didn't return 0, some other object. I tried to simplify the question. I think this is what I want

Comment: You simplified it too much man, now you made Jean Logeart misinterpret your code... Just post your real code or a relevant example

Comment: matchElements(x,y) can return Some(object) if a condition is met else None, right? Would it be wrong to use John's answer then? I am going to try it soon. I can't post the real code because it has lots of classes and stuff that would make no sense. Agree, I should have thought of a better example.

Comment: It seems yield doesn't work as a "return" here. I thought it would.

Comment: Here it's normal because the value is never used. In your code, I don't know, but a for-yield returns a list

Comment: Concerning Jean's answer, yes, it works and is the faster way to do it (although it's no use writing your own method for this), but I think an explanation on `yield` would be more helpful to you, if we had an example of what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [`find`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@find(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option[A]), it finds the first element of the sequence satisfying a predicate, if any:

```
def returnMatchedElement(x: Int, l: List[Int], f: (Int,Int) => Boolean): Option[Int] = {
  l.find(y => f(x, y))
}
```

Comment: And returns an arbitrary value otherwise. How do I know the 0 was or was not in the list ? Does not seem like a good idea

Comment: Based on the original code, I thought it was the idea.

Comment: Maybe it was, but since it's bad it should not be in an answer, I think

Comment: I added a comment on that

Comment: See the last comment of the OP, the 0 was unintended

Comment: Ok, I think to be used in a find function, f must return Boolean. So, I changed the question a bit and would you please look into it? Sorry about the confusion. As I said before, I can't paste the whole code and this is what I thought would be a minimal working example.